# Datastream datatype changes

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-datastream

I have a Datastream job running that is connected to my-sql instance and writing events to gcs bucket .

Now the source my sql server has datatype change in of its column .. how can we handle the datatype change gracefully in google Datastream so that the datatype change column is also loading data accurately